# How do I know when the IMAGE_THUNK_DATA array terminates?

Tags: c++, c, windows, portable-executable

The IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR array terminates when an IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR structure is filled with all zeros.

Each IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR struct has 2 members, OriginalFirstThunk and FirstThunk which contain an RVA to parallel IMAGE_THUNK_DATA arrays.

Does the IMAGE_THUNK_DATA array get terminated with an IMAGE_THUNK_DATA struct that is filled with zeros at the end too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [Matt Pietrek article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301808.aspx) has the information you need:

> Each IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR typically points to two essentially
>   identical arrays. These arrays have been called by several names, but
>   the two most common names are the Import Address Table (IAT) and the
>   Import Name Table (INT). Figure 6 shows an executable importing some
>   APIs from USER32.DLL.
>
> Both arrays have elements of type IMAGE_THUNK_DATA, which is a
>   pointer-sized union. Each IMAGE_THUNK_DATA element corresponds to one
>   imported function from the executable. The ends of both arrays are
>   indicated by an IMAGE_THUNK_DATA element with a value of zero.

Comment: All the best information on such matters came from Matt Pietrek so his is a good name to include in any web searches!

Comment: The article is accessible from here since the MSDN url seems dead: http://bytepointer.com/resources/pietrek_in_depth_look_into_pe_format_pt2.htm